# how to call API post method in karma unit testing and get response from it in angular 4

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write karma unit test cases in angular 4 to get response from post method. I required data coming from API to write further test cases. My sample code snippet is as follows it run but I am not able to get response.

spec.ts

```
  describe('Login service : ', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
  }));

afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (backend: HttpTestingController) => {
backend.verify();
}));


 beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();

debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#userName'));
htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;

 });

  it(`should emit 'true' for 200 Ok status `, async(inject([LoginService, HttpTestingController],
(service: LoginService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
  service.login({ userName: 'CF09221601k', password: 'LK6XOMPBRkH0', BrowserInfo: 'chrome 46.0.2490.86' }).subscribe((next) => {
    expect(next).toBeTruthy();
  });
  backend.expectOne('api/ValidateClientLogin').flush(null,
    { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
})));
```

loginService.ts

```
export class LoginService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

public login(user) {
    return this.httpClient.post(APPCONFIG.WEBSERVICE_URL + APIURL.ValidateClientLogin, user, {observe: 'response'});
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's something you want to do? it looks like your use case can be better fir for end to end testing

Comment: 1. Why do you have two separate units (the LoginComponent and LoginService) in the same unit tests? 2. And where are either of them in the setup? 3. Why do you have both the real and mock HTTP clients in the setup? 4. And if you want to test receiving a response, why don't you `flush` it per [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests)?

Comment: 1.I tried to follow standards that is why i made two separate units for services (frequently used) and this is imported in loginComponent.ts file which is second unit .3.real HttpClients are used here to get data while running the apllication using ng serve. and  trying to use mock http to write test case to get response from API for testing purpose 4. thanks for document.

Comment: 1. That's why you'd separate them in your code, but doesn't explain why you have two units in the same unit test. At the very simplest: why does the `beforeEach` set up something that *isn't being used in the tests?!* 3. That's why you'd have the real client import *in your actual app*, but doesn't explain why you'd have it in the tests.

Comment: 1.write this code to check is it possible to call login function from loginService to make API call and get response or their any other method.
I am new to karma testing,trying to study how interacts with API and read response,if any documentation please suggest